# How to remove duplicate rows in dataframe spark using Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to remove duplicates from the result of joining 2 dataframes as show below. Is there a better way to join or a better way to drop duplicates so that I can achieve the desired dataframe?

I have dataframe A (df_A) as below:

```
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|ID_A     |1ST_NM_A|2ND_NM_A|ADDRESS1_A             |ADDRESS2_A|CITY_A  |ZIP_A    |PHONE_A   |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS  |802035401|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS  |802053436|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS  |862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
```

and dataframe B (df_B) as follows:

```
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|ID_B     |1ST_NM_B|2ND_NM_B|ADDRESS1_B             |ADDRESS2_B|CITY_B  |ZIP_B    |PHONE_B   |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS  |862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS  |802035401|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS  |802053436|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
```

I have millions of records, this sample is just one record with ID = 134305632. As you can see, both dataframe contains same data. It is possible that data in both dataframe for a given ID might not be the same though. It is just the same for this particular ID

My desired result is as follows:

```
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+-------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|ID_A     |1ST_NM_A|2ND_NM_A|ADDRESS1_A             |ADDRESS2_A|CITY_A  |ZIP_A    |PHONE_A   |ID_B   |1ST_NM_B|2ND_NM_B|ADDRESS1_B             |ADDRESS2_B|CITY_B  |ZIP_B    |PHONE_B   |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+-------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS |862365146|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS   |862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA       |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS |802035401|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS    |802035401|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS |802053436|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS    |802053436|9232122398|
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
```

I performed the join operation and did a dropDuplicates, I came with the result below which is not my desired result.

```
val dedupped_df = df_A.join(df_B, col("ID_A") === col("ID_B"), "inner")
                     .dropDuplicates("ID_A", "ADDRESS1_A", "ADDRESS2_A", "CITY_A", "ZIP_A")
dedupped_df.show()

+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+----------+------+---------+----------+
|ID_A     |1ST_NM_A|2ND_NM_A|ADDRESS1_A             |ADDRESS2_A|CITY_A  |ZIP_A    |PHONE_A   |ID_B    |1ST_NM_B|2ND_NM_B|ADDRESS1_B   |ADDRESS2_B|CITY_B|ZIP_B    |PHONE_B   |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+----------+------+---------+----------+
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA       |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST|NA        |DALLAS|862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS |802035401|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST|NA        |DALLAS|862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS |862365146|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST|NA        |DALLAS|862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS |802053436|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST|NA        |DALLAS|862365146|9232122398|
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+----------+------+---------+----------+
```

Below is the resulting dataframe after joining before dropping duplicates

```
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|ID_A     |1ST_NM_A|2ND_NM_A|ADDRESS1_A             |ADDRESS2_A|CITY_A  |ZIP_A    |PHONE_A   |ID_B    |1ST_NM_B|2ND_NM_B|ADDRESS1_B             |ADDRESS2_B|CITY_B  |ZIP_B    |PHONE_B   |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS |802035401|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS |802035401|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS  |862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS |802035401|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS  |802053436|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS |802035401|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS  |802035401|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS |802053436|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS |802053436|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS  |862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS |802053436|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS  |802053436|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS |802053436|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS  |802035401|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS |862365146|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS |862365146|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS  |862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS |862365146|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS  |802053436|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS |862365146|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS  |802035401|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |786 BULIAN ST          |NA        |DALLAS  |862365146|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |8898 N SIMS ST         |NA        |DALLAS  |802053436|9232122398|
|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |324 DROOP STREET APT 33|NA        |WESTPORT|530298435|9232122398|134305632|BAVAL   |WELLS   |143 N 24TH BLV         |NA        |DALLAS  |802035401|9232122398|
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+------ --+--------+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: why you are not doing union ? when u have same data in both the df

Answer (score 0):

```
df.dropDuplicates()
// also you can set columns
```